# How to send email to multiple recipients laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, eloquent, swiftmailer

I am trying to create an application where one of the features is to send email to multiple addresses, and it has not been easy. I used a foreach loop, but whenever an error occurs, most especially if the recipient mail address is not valid the application stops.

This is my code

```
public function sendemails(Request $request){

     $email = $this->emailSetUp($request);

     $emails = $email->recipients;
     foreach ($emails as $value) {
        try{
            $mail =  Mail::to($value)->send(new SendEmail($email));
        }catch( \Swift_RfcComplianceException $e){
            $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
            preg_match_all($pattern, $e, $matches);
            $match = implode(',',$matches[0]);
            $mail_t_del = Email::where('email','LIKE', '%'.$match)->first();

            $mail_t_del->delete();
           Log::info($match .' '. 'deleted');

           $email = $this->emailSetUp($request);  
           $mail =  Mail::send(new SendEmail($email));      
       }
   }

}
```

How can i

1. Send the message to multiple recipients and also make it fail proof, by continuing after the exception has been thrown.
2. How can i track the progress of the application i.e know the emails that has been sent and the on that has been rejected.

Comment: Have you tried just passing an array of addresses?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array of emails.

see here for details

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.html#method_to

Also I suggest that you create a custom request to check to make sure that emails are valid before processing.

You can see how to do that here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests

Comment: You can create custom requests in which you set your validation methods and messages for when they do not validate.https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 2):

**- Send the message to multiple recipients**

pass all the emails in your mail class

Example:

```
 Mail::to($users)->send(new SendEmail($yourData));
```

put your codes in try catch

so that you can ignore exception and continue to send other mails

**- Track the progress**

If you want to get which mails are sent or not

then handle it on catch statement exception and log it in file or DB

Comment: i wrapped my code in try catch, but the loop does'nt continue after it fails the first time, and i used the 'continue' keyword in my forloop

Answer (score 0):

To send an email to multiple recipients without displaying the sent email to all recipients, try this:
This method will loop through the emails supplied for form or database. in this example the user IDs come from form requests, then, email is retrieved from the database for selected users.

```
foreach($request->get_emails as $i => $a){
        $user = User::find($a);
        Mail::send('emails.template', ['name' => $user['name'], 'body' => $request->body], function ($m) use($user) {
            $m->from('info@example.com', 'Sender Name');
            $m->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('this is the subject');
        });
    }
```

Also, you may choose to display emails to all recipient. To do that, try:

```
    $emails = ['eamil1@example.com', 'email2@example.com','email3@example.com'];

    Mail::send('emails.template', [], function($m) use ($emails)
    {    
        $m->to($emails)->subject('This is the email subject');    
    });
```